# I'm trying a MCQ's Distractor Generator getting the following error can anyone explan?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp

following is code where i get a error:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[1])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y1.shape[0], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Fitting Data:

```
model.fit(X, y1, epochs=20, batch_size=128)
model.fit(X, y2, epochs=20, batch_size=128)
model.fit(X, y3, epochs=20, batch_size=128)
```

the following is the output code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 139, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y1, epochs=20, batch_size=128)

File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (13595, 2)

Comment: So you just want an explanation why the error happens?

Comment: What's your data like? Does it have a time dimension?

Comment: I think error is self explanatory. It is expecting 3 dimension, you are passing array of 2d.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes sir